What if a Shudra wishes to study Shruti (Vedas & Upanishads)?
What if a Shudra wishes to study Shruti (Vedas & Upanishads)?
Of course he/she can study them online but what if they wish to do so under the guidance of a Guru?
I know the Dharmshastras don't allow this but what if they want to, after all, few people study Shruti via a Guru under proper tradition circumstances (after sacred thread cermony); shouldn't a Shudra who by his own will be allowed to study them?

I) Your first question What if a Shudra wishes to study Shruti (Vedas & Upanishads)?
There is highly interesting sloke from Sanyāsa Dharma Samhitā(सन्यासधर्म संहिता) [Page:24] which says that everyone is born a Shūdra [ignorant of the path to spiritual knowledge], and by our karma and culture we become Dvijas(द्विज/Twice Born). Eventually, at the final evolvement of Brahma jnāna one is termed as Brāhmana.

जन्मना जायते शूद्रः संस्काराद्द्विज उच्यते |
वेदाभ्यासाद्भवेद्विप्रो ब्रहाज्ञानाच्च ब्राह्मणः ||

janmanā jāyate sudrah samskārāt dvij uchchte |
vedābyāsātbhavetvipro brahmajānācca  brāhmanah ||

Everyone is born Sudra, by accepting Samskara [Purificatory process] 
one becomes a Dvija[Twice Born], By study of Veda one becomes Vipra, 
Knower of Brahman is Brahmana.

- Sanyāsa Dharma Samhitā: Page-24. 


According to the above sūtra anybody can study anything about Hinduism and related Sāstras such as Veda, Vedānga, Shad Darshana (Vaisheshika, Nyāya, Sānkhya, Yoga, Mīmāmsa and Vedānta), Brahma Sūtra, Dharmasāstra, Purāna, Itihāsa, and Pāncharātra.
II) Your second question Of course he/she can study them online but what if they wish to do so under the guidance of a Guru?
You can't study vedas online and your attempt will be futile!
Sir John George Woodroffe (aka Arthur Avalon), was a British Orientalist, who was then a judge in a colonial Indian court, hearing a particular case in which he could not come into conclusion. He felt he was deprived of all his senses and could not focus. It was later found that a Tāntric Sādhu in court campus was making a Tāntric Prayoga, known as Bedana Prayoga(भेदन/Act of breaking/dividing/fracture/breach/separating) which is one of Ashta Karma(अष्टकर्म/Eight Acts), on him. This incidence made Woodroffe curious and spent rest of his life studying Indian Tāntrism and came out with the famous book “The Serpent Power”.
Please know that almost all of Tantra Sastra Grantas have been written only in Sanskrit. Exceptionally, John Woodroffe has written Principles of Tantra, which is an English translation of the Bengali work Tantratattva(तंत्रतत्त्व) written by his guru Shivachandra Vidyārnava, mentions that each Krāntā has it's own 64 sets of Shāktāgamas. There are 3 Krāntās, which makes a total of 192 Shāktāgamas. Sir John George Woodroffe extensive and complex
published works on the Tantras, and other Hindu traditions, stimulated
a wide-ranging interest in Hindu philosophy and yoga.

Being a non-Dvija, Sir John George Woodroffe was accepted by his guru (Sri Shivachandra Vidyārnava) and learned, beginning from Sanskrit language, the principles of Sākta and Tantra philosophies and other Sāstras.

This story will definitely inspire and motivate every non-Dvija who wants to take up and study Philosophy of Hinduism.
III) Your third and final question I know the Dharmshastras don't allow this but what if they want to, after all, few people study Shruti via a Guru under proper tradition circumstances (after sacred thread cermony); shouldn't a Shudra who by his own will be allowed to study them?
It is true that Dharmshastras don't allow but Skanda Purana Vol.18 Book VI, Nagar Kanda, Chapter 239, Verse 31 does!

जन्मना जायते शूद्रः संस्कारात् द्विज उच्यते।
शापानुग्रहसामर्थ्यं तथा क्रोधः प्रसन्नता ।|31||

janmanā jāyate śūdraḥ saṃskārāddvija ucyate |
śāpānugrahasāmarthyaṃ tathā krodhaḥ prasannatā || 31 ||

A Man is no better than a sudra[शूद्रः] at his birth. He is called Dvija 
[द्विज/Twice Born] due to the consecration[संस्कार]. The ability to curse[शाप]
and to bless[अनुग्रह], the state of being angry[क्रोधः] and pleased[प्रसन्न] and 
the status of being the foremost in all three worlds occur only in Brahmana.

- Skanda Purana: Ch-239, Verse 31.


Like Sir John George Woodroffe was accepted, a true Guru will never hesitate to accept an enthusiastic students as disciple. Please read Kulārṇava tantram(कुलार्णवतन्त्रम्) to know about the qualities of a Guru and relationship between Guru-Sisya.
Conclusion:
Therefore, no body is Brahmana until Ātmajnānam (आत्मज्ञानम्/ஆத்ம ஞானம்/Self-knowledge) is acquired, so don't hesitate to study whatever you want.
Good Luck!

Understood, Thanks! But what about the many Dharmic texts suggesting that varṇa is by birth only? Bhishma even says that a 10 years old Brāhmaṇa is like a father of 100 years old Kṣatriya. Even Chandogya Upanishad suggests it in 5.10.07.

@Vedant Singh, Lord krishna says in BG[18.41] as The duties of the Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas, and Shudras—are distributed according to their qualities, in accordance with their guṇas [and not by birth]. [Continued below...]

Chandogya Upanishad [5.10.7] says Among them, those who did good work in this world [in their past life] attain a good birth accordingly. They are born as a brāhmin, a kṣatriya, or a vaiśya. But those who did bad work in this world [in their past life] attain a bad birth accordingly, being born as a dog, a pig, or as a casteless person. But Krishna overrides that by asserting “you may be Brahman by birth but only qualities determines who you really are. Standing example is Dronachāryā in Mahābhāratam.

@Vedant Singh , you said many Dharmic texts suggesting that varṇa is by birth only. Will you please quote a Darmasastra who says so? Thanks.

Anyone can study Sruti under the guidance of a Guru.
It is only the commentarial traditions like the Dharma Sastras and some Puranas that prohibit Sudras and women from reading the Vedas. We must remember that these texts were not written by infallible people.

The Dharma Sastras, Puranas and the Angas of the Vedas are full of
diverse opinions on any one point under consideration; for their
composers were under the influence of different gunas.

Srimad Devi Bhagavatam IV.IV
There is no need to accept this prohibition. In fact the discriminatory nature of such prohibition makes these verses invalid and they shouldn't be followed.
No discrimination

If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
it should not be practiced. It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
and even of Kama.

Kurma Purana I.2.54
Moreover varnas are to be determined by conduct and not by birth.

Maheshwara said, ‘..Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor
learning, nor offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring
upon one the regenerate status. Verily, the conduct is the only
ground. All Brahmanas in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of
conduct. A Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as
possessed of the status of a Brahmana. The status of a Brahma, O
auspicious lady [Uma], is equal wherever it exists. Even this is my
opinion. He, indeed, is a Brahmana in which the status of Brahma
exists – that condition which is bereft of attributes and which has no
stain attached to it. The boon giving Brahma, when he created all
creatures, himself said that the distribution of human beings in four
orders dependent on birth is only for purposes of classification.'

Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII
How would you know who is a Sudra given that varna is not dependent on birth?
Moreover there are explicit statements in scripture that say that all persons are entitled to get knowledge.
The sage Bhrigu said,

‘There is really no distinction between the different orders. The
whole world at first consisted of Brahmanas. Created (equal) by
Brahman, men have, in consequence of their acts, become distributed
into different orders. They that became fond of indulging in desire
and enjoying pleasures, possessed of the attributes of severity and
wrath, endued with courage, and unmindful of the duties of piety and
worship, - these Brahmanas possessing the attributes of passion, -
became Kshatriyas. Those Brahmanas again who, without attending to the
duties laid down for them, became possessed of both the attributes of
Goodness and Passion, and took to the professions of cattle-rearing
and agriculture, became Vaisyas. Those Brahmanas again that became
fond of untruth and injuring other creatures, possessed of cupidity, -
engaged in all kinds of acts for a living, and fallen away from the
purity of behaviour, and thus wedded to the attributes of Darkness,
became Sudras. Separated by these occupations, Brahmanas, falling away
from their order, became members of the other three orders. All the
four orders, therefore, have always the right to the performance of
all pious duties and of sacrifices. Even thus were the four orders at
first created equal by Brahman who ordained for all of them (the
observances disclosed in) the words of Brahma (in the Vedas). Through
cupidity alone, many fell away, and became possessed by ignorance. The
Brahmanas are always devoted to the scripture on Brahma; and mindful
of vows and restraints, are capable of grasping the conception of
Brahma. Their penances therefore never go for nothing. They amongst
them are not Brahmanas that are incapable of understanding that every
created thing is Supreme Brahma.

(Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CLXXXVIII)
The famous Rishi Yajnavalkya continued,

’ .. All orders of men are Brahmanas. All are sprung from Brahma. All
men utter Brahma. Aided by an understanding that. I inculcated this
science teaching of Prakriti and Purusha. Indeed this whole universe
is Brahma. From the mouth of Brahma sprung the Brahmanas; from his
arms, sprung the Kshatriyas; from his navel, the Vaisysa; and from his
feet, the Sudras. All the orders, (having sprung in this way) should
not be regarded as pilfering from one another. Impelled by ignorance,
all men meet with death and attain, O King, to birth that is the cause
of acts. Divested of knowledge, all orders of men, dragged in terrible
ignorance, fall into varied orders of being due to the principles that
flow from Prakriti. For this reason, all should, by every means, seek
to acquire knowledge. I have told thee that every person is entitled
to strive for its acquisition. One that is possessed of knowledge is a
Brahmana. Others, (viz., Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas and Sudras) are
possessed of knowledge. Hence this science of emancipation is always
open to them all.

(Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCXIX)
